# Can someone explain what Data Flows are used to in Esper?

Tags: esper, dataflow, nesper

I read about Data Flows in the esper docs and dont understand where in the application it should be used.

```
  create dataflow HelloWorldDataFlow
  BeaconSource -> helloworld.stream { text: 'hello world' , iterations: 1}
  LogSink(helloworld.stream) {}
```

When i run the code above nothing happens when i .run() the flow using EPDataFlowINstance

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the log isn't configured right. There is some information in the documentation on log4j configuration.

In my experience dataflows aren't so important because input and output is often already given and doesn't need to be declarative. With dataflows it can get small performance gain from the fact that its more low level.